# NTFSSecurity in PowerShell Will Not Remove Recursive Unresolved SIDs

Tags: powershell, automation, ntfs

I am trying to scan and then remove all unresolved SIDs in my environment. Finding the SIDs with the PowerShell module NTFSSecurity works great. It is when I try to pipe in the remove command that it does not seem to remove anything. According to the documentation on https://github.com/raandree/NTFSSecurity this should work. Does anyone have any experience with this module? Does anyone recommend anything else? I would love to automate this process considering I have 85,000+ unresolved SIDs in my org environment.

```
Script that does not work:
dir '*my directory*' -Recurse | Get-NTFSOrphanedAccess | Remove-NTFSAccess

Script that does work that returns all my unresolved SIDs
dir '*my directory*' -Recurse | Get-NTFSOrphanedAccess
```

Comment: Is it an inherited permission?

Comment: @DougMaurer Yes, the permissions it is attempting to remove are inherited.

Comment: There is your answer. You can explicitly remove inherited permissions without first turning off inheritance at the targeted item.

Comment: @DougMaurer I will try it against a folder that has uninherited permissions and see what happens.